# managing and documenting a multiline substitution in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, string-substitution

I have recently been learning about the `\x` modifier in Perl Best Practices, enabling you to do cool things like multi-line indentation and documentation:

```
$txt =~ m/^                     # anchor at beginning of line
      The\ quick\ (\w+)\ fox    # fox adjective
      \ (\w+)\ over             # fox action verb
      \ the\ (\w+) dog          # dog adjective
      (?:                       # whitespace-trimmed comment:
        \s* \# \s*              #   whitespace and comment token
        (.*?)                   #   captured comment text; non-greedy!
        \s*                     #   any trailing whitespace
      )?                        # this is all optional
      $                         # end of line anchor
     /x;                        # allow whitespace
```

However, I was unable to do the equivalent for find/replace string substitutions? Is there some other similar best practice that should be used to more effectively manage complex substitutions?

*Edit* Take this for an example:

```
$test =~ s/(src\s*=\s*['"]?)(.*?\.(jpg|gif|png))/${1}something$2/sig;
```

Is there a similar way that this could be documented using multi-line/whitespace for better readability?

Many thanks

Comment: Please give a little example of what it was you had trouble doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've chosen not to provide an example of something that doesn't work, I'll offer a few guesses at what you might be doing wrong:

- Note that the delimiter (in your case `/`) cannot appear inside any comments inside the regex, because then they'll be indicating the end of the regex. For example, this:

  ```
  s/foo # this is interesting and/or cool
   /bar/x
  ```

  will not work, because the regex is terminated by the slash between `and` and `or`.
- Note that `/x` does not work on the replacement-string, only on the regex itself. For example this:

  ```
  s/foo/bar # I love the word bar/x
  ```

  will replace `foo` with `bar # I love the word bar`.

  If you really want to be able to put comments in the replacement-string, then I suppose you could use a replacement-*expression* instead, using the `/e` flag. That would let you use the full syntax of Perl. For example:

  ```
  s/foo/'bar' # I love the word bar/e
  ```

Here is an example that *does* work:

```
$test =~
  s/
    # the regex to replace:
    (src\s*=\s*['"]?)      # src=' or src=" (plus optional whitespace)
    (.*?\.(jpg|gif|png))   # the URI of the JPEG or GIF or PNG image
  /
    # the string to replace it with:
    $1 .                   # src=' or src=" (unchanged)
    'something' .          # insert 'something' at the start of the URI
    $2                     # the original URI
  /sige;
```

Comment: This is a good answer so far. But you could point out that the choice of delimiter is arbitrary: `s{foo}` and on a new line `{bar}` etc. This sometimes avoids the `/e` switch.

Comment: @amon: I don't follow. How would the choice of a different delimiter affect the use of `/e`?

Comment: It allows more layout options than the slash delimiter, as the substitution may be seperated from the pattern by whitespace incl. newlines. This would solve your first example, but wouldn't make much difference with your last. Except that curlies may be preferable anyway when enclosing code.

Comment: @amon: O.K., yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: Thank you both. This answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

If we just add the `/x`, we can break up the regular expression portion easily, including allowing comments.

```
my $test = '<img src = "http://www.somewhere.com/im/alright/jack/keep/your/hands/off/of/my/stack.gif" />';

$test =~ s/
    ( src \s* = \s* ['"]? ) # a src attribute ...
    ( .*? 
      \. (jpg|gif|png)      # to an image file type, either jpeg, gif or png
    )
    /$1something$2/sigx     # put 'something' in front of it
    ;
```

You have to use the evaluation switch (`/e`) if you want to break up the replacement. But the multi-line for the match portion, works fine.

Notice that I did not have to separate `$1`, because `$1something` is not a valid identifier anyway, so my version of Perl, at least, does not get confused.

For most of my evaluated replacements, I prefer the bracket style of substitution delimiter:

```
$test =~ s{
      ( src \s* = \s* ['"]? ) # a src attribute ... '
      ( .*? 
        \. (jpg|gif|png)      # to an image file type, either jpeg, gif or png
      )
    }{
        $1 . 'something' . $2
    }sigxe 
    ;
```

just to make it look more code-like.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
$test =~ s/(src\s*=\s*['"]?)    # first group
        (.*?\.(jpg|gif|png))        # second group
        /${1}something$2/sigx;
```

should and *does* work indeed. Of course, you can't use this on the right part, unless you use somethig like :

```
$test =~ s/(src\s*=\s*['"]?)    # first group
        (.*?\.(jpg|gif|png))        # second group
        /
        $1              # Get 1st group
        . "something"   # Append ...
        . $2            # Get 2d group
        /sigxe;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/foo/bar/
```

could be written as

```
s/
   foo     # foo
/
   "bar"   # bar
/xe
```

- `/x` to allow whitespace in the pattern
- `/e` to allow code in the replacement expression